# Aggregating time-based data of multiple patients to daily averages per patient in R

Tags: r, time, time-series, average, mean

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id                time value
01 2014-02-26 13:00:00     6
02 2014-02-26 15:00:00     6
01 2014-02-26 18:00:00     6
04 2014-02-26 21:00:00     7
02 2014-02-27 09:00:00     6
03 2014-02-27 12:00:00     6
```

The dataframe consists of a mood score at different time stamps throughout the day of multiple patients.

I want the dataframe to become like this:

```
id  2014-02-26 2014-02-27
01        6.25       4.32
02        5.39       8.12
03        9.23       3.18
04        5.76       3.95
```

With on each row a patient and in each the column the daily mean of all the days in the dataframe. If there is no mood score on a specific date from a patient, I want the value to be NA.

What is the easiest way to do so using functions like ddply, or from other packages?

---

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L), time = structure(c(1393437600, 
1393444800, 1393455600, 1393466400, 1393509600, 1393520400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L)), .Names = c("id", 
"time", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How did you get the values? For example 6.25 for id 01

Comment: I have made up this values, so they are not the actual daily averages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, you could combine `aggregate` with `reshape` like this:

```
# get means by id-date
temp <- setNames(aggregate(value ~ id + format(time, "%y-%m-%d"), data=df, FUN=mean),
                 c("id", "time", "value"))
# reshape to get dates as columns
reshape(temp, direction="wide", idvar="id", timevar="time")
  id value.14-02-26 value.14-02-27
1  1              6             NA
2  2              6              6
3  4              7             NA
5  3             NA              6
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, this seems to be what you need,

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(id, time1 = format(time, '%Y-%m-%d')) %>% 
  summarise(new = mean(value)) %>% 
  spread(time1, new)

#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#Groups: id [4]

#     id `2014-02-26` `2014-02-27`
#* <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#1     1            6           NA
#2     2            6            6
#3     3           NA            6
#4     4            7           NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend using the `data.table` package, the approach then is very similar to Sotos' `tidiverse` solution.

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(df)

df[, time1 := format(time, '%Y-%m-%d')]

aggregated <- df[, list(meanvalue = mean(value)), by=c("id", "time1")]
aggregated <- dcast.data.table(aggregated, id~time1, value.var="meanvalue")

aggregated
#  id 2014-02-26 2014-02-27
# 1:  1          6         NA
# 2:  2          6          6
# 3:  3         NA          6
# 4:  4         NA          7
```

(I think my result differs, because my System runs on another timezone, I imported the datetime objects as UTC.)